# How to personalize alert buttons - window.confirm() and window.alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have seen many websites that have personalized their alert and confirmation boxes with different button text.

By default, this is what the JavaScript `window.confirm()` function would output:

```
+-----------------------------+
|Message from webpage         |
+-----------------------------+
|Popup text                   |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|   [Ok]     [Cancel]         |
+-----------------------------+
```

But, what if I wanted some customization like custom header text, and custom button text?

```
+-----------------------------+
|My custom Header             |
+-----------------------------+
|Popup text                   |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|   [HELLO]     [GOODBYE]     |
+-----------------------------+
```

Can this be achieved in JavaScript, Jquery, or AJAX (or another language)? If so, could you please show me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Javascript modals are [notoriously difficult (or impossible) to alter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel). Your best bet is to make your own modal popup. Consider jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: FWIW jQuery and AJAX aren't languages

Comment: This is *possible*. There are a couples of post on this site where you can find useful information. e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6929416/1505348

Comment: @Madbreaks what is FWIW? Anyways, you knew what I meant ;)

Comment: FWIW == For What It's Worth

Comment: @pattyd No, I don't know you, your statement led me to believe that you think jQuery and AJAX are programming languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wont discover anything new here. And the comments created say all the most relevant information.

You should look at open source alternatives that have great support and are easy to customize. Take a look at [BootBoxJS](http://bootboxjs.com/) (it depends on jQuery).

In that site you can find examples of alerts, dialogs, and other useful tools. e.g.

[image: confirm dialog personalized]

To use the mentioned soft:

1. Download the [js library compressed](http://bootboxjs.com/#download) (including js, css, etc)
2. Unzip the file whatever you want to.
3. Then copy and paste [the example code](http://bootboxjs.com/#usage) and save this as `example.html` or whatever you want to.
4. Now change the links to make it point to your downloaded files (see how I changed [my file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5737073/))
5. Save the file and test it with your preferred browser.

I just did it and it works perfect! (Under Firefox and Chromium)

**NOTE**: I tested it with the new version of BootStrap (v.3) and it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @Lucio, I actually like this allot. I cant get it to work though! Could you give some installation steps?

Comment: See my updated answer. I tested it by my self. Hopefully, will be useful :)

Comment: :) also, I cant find where to download the js library compressed... that link just brings me to the home page

Comment: Oh men, you're vague. [Here is the link](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/zipball/v3.2.0). You need to read more :)

Comment: what am i doing wrong? I seriously cant get this working :( http://pastebin.com/ijyhvhCR

Comment: @pattyd I've created [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31288/room-for-lucio-and-pattyd) to explain further.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is that you can't , prompts do not support this feature,

However you could use Jquery or build your own modal/ dialog to emulate this functionality.

See the [jQuery UI Dialo](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)g for ideas and examples.

Setting up the example from the page check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/3eaqv/)

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

The CSS is to large to post, but you can link this file :

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: thanks! i will check that out! So, those other websites didn't use JavaScript then?

Comment: Yes, the used it , is just that they didn't use the navite prompts, they probably used a custom script with an overlay or modal

Comment: Oh, could you show me how to use a modal or overlay? Or would that be harder? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I just added a jsfiddle and the code, but really you should read the documentation, is fairly easy

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for all the help, all of you guys!

Comment: How would I use one button to open a link instead of close? Or execute some PHP?

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle, to show you how to open a new window, to execute PHP you could either perform an ajax call or submit a form

Comment: how would I name that popup function, then call the function on button click?

Comment: i get this unwanted result: http://snag.gy/RKGdv.jpg why is this happening?????? My code is here: http://pastebin.com/8qGbHgMe

Comment: you need to add the CSS file

Comment: what CSS file? Could you post some code for the css?

Comment: I added the link for a CSS file , you can use that one on your script

Comment: Thanks very much! For now I am experimenting with the answer from @Lucio... It is a very cool way to do it! Thanks for all the help! +1

Comment: no problem, glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

No. A simple review of [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.alert) may be useful.  Java applets have similarly (but distinctly different) styled UI elements that may be what you've seen in the past.

If you wanted to you could create your own dialog boxes using HTML/CSS/JavaScript that act like user agent dialog boxes, but that's a lot of work for the result.

Comment: are you sure? I have seen this done before.... It doesn't have to be with JS,JQ,or AJAX... any other language will do

Comment: Your question is tagged `javascript`, so my answer applies to JavaScript.