# Create confirmation box with "accept" and "deny"

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

How would I make a dialog box with two options, accept and deny, when a user visits my website ? I need the accept button to continue to my website, and the deny button to take the visitor to their last webpage.

So far I have:

```
var confirmation = confirm('Do you want to continue on this website?');
if (!confirmation){
    // Redirect the user to his last webpage:
    history.go(-1);
}
```

Comment: you will have to use a 3rd party library such as bootstrap or jqueryui.

Comment: A lot of frameworks provide customizable pop-ups. Is using one of those an option? (@DanielA.White - You don't **have** to use a third-party library; it's just a lot more convenient if you do.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929416/custom-confirm-dialog-in-javascript?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887029/how-to-implement-confirmation-dialog-in-jquery-ui-dialog?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929370/how-to-personalize-alert-buttons-window-confirm-and-window-alert?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jquery then you include Jquery in your page and define following function

```
function confirmation(question) {
var defer = $.Deferred();
$('<div></div>')
    .html(question)
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Confirmation',
        buttons: {
            "Accept": function () {
                defer.resolve("true");//this text 'true' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Deny": function () {
                defer.resolve("false");//this text 'false' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
return defer.promise();
};
```

Then use it in following way

```
 confirmation('Do you want to continue on this website?').then(function (answer) {

                if (answer == "false") {
                    // your logic

                }
                else if (answer == "true") {
                    // your logic
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery UI you could do it like this:

### HTML:

```
<div id="ask">
    <h1> Some title </h1>
    <p> Some info </p>
</div>
```

### JS:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#ask" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Allow": function() {
            alert("You have been allowed");
            // more allow code here
        },
        "Deny": function() {
            alert("You have been denied");
            history.go(-1);
            // more deny code here
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yCkjR/1/)

You will have to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) in your page.